# How to set checkbox with no html attribute and xpath is also dynamic

Tags: watir

I have following HTML code rendered for checkbox.This checkbox is appearing on pop-up window.
I tried to set this checkbox with **:index** attribute but getting an error 'Object disabled' but checkbox is default visible.

Then i tried to identify this element using :xpath attribute...The xpath value is is not constant.. each time popup opens the :xpath chanhge

**xpath:** //*[@id="*ngdialog19*"]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input

**HTML Code**

```
<input class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" data-ng-model="serviceLinePrice.selected" data-ng-disabled="serviceLinePrice.IsOneOff" data-ng-change="onSelectChange()" type="checkbox">
```

How i can set this checbox?
Any hint please?

Checkbox is nested under `<td>` element. 
The html code as following:

```
<td data-title-text=" ">
            <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" data-ng-model="serviceLinePrice.selected" data-ng-disabled="serviceLinePrice.IsOneOff" data-ng-change="onSelectChange()" type="checkbox">
```

**This is complete code**
I tried to access checkbox by index attribute (:index, 1) but there was neither error nor checkbox selected...

```
<tr class="ng-scope" data-ng-repeat="testline in $data" data-ng-disabled="testline .isOneOff">
        <td data-title-text=" ">
            <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" data-ng-model="testline .selected" data-ng-disabled="testline .IsOneOff" data-ng-change="onSelectChange()" type="checkbox">
        </td></tr>
```

Comment: Can you give us the html "around" the checkbox ?

Comment: I added html code in my question.

Comment: Do you have a way to target the cell, the row, or the table ?

Comment: Is the data-ng-model attribute value unique?

Comment: @Fabrice31 not sure what you mean ?

Comment: @JustinKo are you sure data-ng-model will work? i tried and got the error 'undefined local variable or method `ng' for #<Object:0x0000000316c490>'

Comment: You can locate the checkbox by the data-ng-model using `browser.checkbox(:data_ng_model => 'serviceLinePrice.selected').set`. However, it might not solve your problem - ie presumably you will still get the object disabled error. You need to figure out why the checkbox is disabled.